# Arduino mini pro + Mac 10.9.5 + Bluetooth Mate Silver

Tags: arduino, android-bluetooth

I am using Arduino mini pro and just purchased Bluetooth Mate Silver. I have connected the two and supplied power. The bluetooth device is blinking. I have followed the steps to pair the device with my Mac (10.9.5).

- The device shows up as RNBT-EFD 7 on my bluetooth.
- I use serial port: /dev/tty.RNBT-EFD7-RNI-SPP

When I upload my sketch, it connects and the green light comes up but then I get the following error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

and "sometimes" the following in addition; when I switch TX and RX i don't get this error (note that they mentioned in Mate the bluetooth device can connect to the board just like the breakout and with breakout TX -> TX; RX -> RX:

```
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Other times I get this error:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/tty.RNBT-EFD7-RNI-SPP": Resource busy
ioctl("TIOCMGET"): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I installed the drives again, and again. I have pushed the reset on pro mini before the upload and after the upload before the error messages appear and nothing works. I have tried many solutions that I saw to this problem and some had 40+ rating but it's just not working.

I have also changed the user for /dev/tty.RNBT-EFD7-RNI-SPP to be me and used chmod 755 on it.. still getting the following error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

It's getting quite frustrating.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include "TimeAlarms.h"

RTC_DS1307 rtc;

void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  rtc.begin();

 setSyncProvider(syncProvider);   // the function to get the time from the RTC


  Alarm.alarmRepeat(10,30,0,startBuz);  // 10:30am every day
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(16,36,15,startBuz);  // 4:30pm every day 
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(22,30,0,startBuz);  // 10:30pm every day 

  Serial.begin(9600);
//  bluetooth.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

  //printing the current time
  DateTime now = rtc.now();

  Serial.print(now.year());
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.month());
  Serial.print('/');
  Serial.print(now.day());
  Serial.print(' ');
  Serial.print(now.hour());
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.minute());
  Serial.print(':');
  Serial.print(now.second());
  Serial.println();

   Alarm.delay(1000); // wait one second between clock display
}

void startBuz(){
// so some stuff here 
}
```

Comment: What tool do you use to upload your code, an FTDI chip? because that's a programmer error. Can you try to upload a simple blink sketch (without bluetooth module)? Does it work?

Comment: I am using Arduino mini connected to the breadboard. I originally uploaded my program using a breakout and things works well. But now I am trying to use bluetooth instead of a physical wire. so I hooked that up and I haven't been successful. I have updated my question to include s snapshot of my code.